# Get distinct values of multiple data attributes from file and store them in a different file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a file contains data records in the following format

```
 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

and i want to get the distinct values of multiple indexes of attributes.for example indexes 5,6

I implemented a code to get these distinct values but for only one attribute.

How Can i get the distinct Values of more than one attribute and store them in one file !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to load the lines from the input file first `GetEntities`, convert to the in-memory format next, execute the query or apply transformation `GetValues` and finally dump the result to the output file. `System.Linq` together with `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces are giving you very powerful APIs and you should be able to accomplish all you need with their help. Many useful APIs are also available in `System.IO` namespace for the file operations such as `ReadAllLines` or `WriteAllLines`. See the code snippet below.

C# code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entities = GetEntities("data.csv").ToList();

    var columns = new[] { 4, 10 };
    var values = GetValues(entities, columns);
    File.WriteAllLines("4-and-10.txt", values.Distinct());
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(IEnumerable<Entity> entities, params int[] columns)
{
    var values = new List<string>();
    foreach (var distinctValues in columns.Select(index => GetValues(entities, index).Distinct()))
    {
        values.AddRange(distinctValues);
    }
    return values;
}

private static IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities(string file, char separator = ',')
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(x => new Entity
    {
        Values = x.Split(separator)
            .Select(c => c.Trim())
            .ToArray()
    });
}

public class Entity
{
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

From the maintainability perspective it might be a good idea to define all the columns with their data types inside `Entity` class as properties which correspond to the columns in your input file, this way you can have more clarity on the data types and may bring `Enums` or references to the other classes to the rescue. The deserialization from comma separated format to more structured in-memory structure often helps to simplify your code and improve the readability, it also separates the concerns of loading the data from the querying.

Comment: But, i need to reed this file as streaming data

Comment: That's what `InternalReadAllLines` method is doing inside standard `File` class, here is the code from the framework `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding)) while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) lines.Add(line);`.

Comment: Actually, i don't understand how your solution get the distinct values for Multiple attributes.

Comment: It is accomplished with the call to `Distinct()`. You can calculate distinct values across single column with it or across multiple ones if you union them first e.g. `GetValues(entities, 4).Union(GetValues(entities, 10)).Distinct()`. You can also union them after calling `Distinct()` for each one independently depending on what you looking for.

Comment: Great, it is now understood (Y)
but, if i want to use looping through different indexes to get their distinct values and write each in the same file. this can be achieved ?

Comment: Updated example with the code snippet of the Distinct method.

Comment: yes i looked at this implementation, but in the call of 
File.WriteAllLines("4-and-10.txt", 
        GetValues(entities, 4).Union(GetValues(entities, 10)).Distinct());
indexes are passed in a static way! how i can pass them as variables

Comment: i will get these indexes in the run time

Comment: Have a look at the latest version of the code, the distinct values are now in the `values` variable. You can work with `values` variable now and do any other manipulations you want.

Comment: yes, but values variable still hold the values of indexes 4 and 10 only ?

Comment: Added new override for the `GetValues` method and passing `var columns = new[] {4, 10};` to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and support